# Get seconds from time without colons HHMMSS in bash

Tags: bash, time

I am currently typing in time to be converted into seconds as `HH:MM:SS` with this:

```
 $(date -d "1970-01-01 $element Z" +%s)
```

I would like to be able to supply the time as HHMMSS without the `:` colons. But have the same outcome. Converted into seconds.

Input:

```
010000 = 60*60*1 = 3600s
004032 = 60*40+32 = 2432s
```

Comment: your input doesn't look like bash code

Comment: This is one case where BSD `date` is superior: `date -jf '%F %H%M%S %z' "1970-01-01 $element +0000" +%s`.

Answer (score 3):

If you have `$element` containing a six-digit string representing a time HHMMSS, you can convert it directly:

```
(( s = 10#${element:0:2}*3600 + 10#${element:2:2}*60 + 10#${element:4} ))
```

This uses parameter expansion to extract the substrings.

You need to prefix them with `10#` so bash doesn't treat them as octal if they begin with zero.

Answer (score 1):

Use parameter expansion to extract the substrings:

```
seconds=$(date -d "1970-01-01 ${element:0:2}:${element:2:2}:${element:4} Z" +%s)
        #                     2 chars from    2 chars from   rest of the
        #                     position 0      position 2     string from 
        #                                                    position 4
```

Comment: Ahhh very nice. I didn't realise you could treat strings as arrays in Bash!! Thanks

Comment: That's not arrays but substrings.

Comment: Ah ok, from a JS minds eye, that looks like an array and index referencing it :D